# How to group widgets in "Add widget" dialog

Tags: android, list, android-appwidget

I have two appWidgets, now if user open "Add widget" dialog, both widgets will be visible in main list. But bundled HTC widgets are grouped by subject. For example clicking on "Calnedar" will bring another list, where user can pick desired design.

Is it possible to reproduce such feature or it is some feature hardcoded to Sense ?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to reproduce such feature or it is some feature hardcoded to Sense ?

That could be a configuration activity. If not, then it is part of the HTC Sense home screen.

Comment: Mmm.. yes.. looks like activity styled to Sense.